# Can't figure out what's causing the IOError is coming from

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, getopts

I've written a script using getopts to accept four user input items (two input files, and two output files). But for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
python2.7 compare_files.py -b /tmp/bigfile.txt -s /tmp/smallfile.txt -n /tmp/notinfile.txt -a /tmp/areinfile.txt
compare_files.py -b <biggerfile> -s <smallerfile> -n <notinfile> -a <areinfile> d
 I/O error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
(<type 'exceptions.IOError'>, IOError(2, 'No such file or directory'), <traceback object at 0x7f10c485c050>)
```

I cant understand which input item variable is causing me problems. Please can someone tell me where I've gone wrong?
Here's the script:

```
import sys, getopt

def main(argv):
    binputfilename = ''
    sinputfilename = ''
    outputfilename1 = ''
    outputfilename2 = ''

    try: 
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "h:b:s:n:a", ["bfile=", "sfile=", "nfile=", "afile="])
    except getopt.GetoptError as (errno, strerror):
        print(str(sys.argv[0]) + " -b <biggerfile> -s <smallerfile> -n <notinfile> -a <areinfile> a")
        print("GetOpts error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror))
        sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print(str(sys.argv[0]) + " -b <biggerfile>  -s <smallerfile> -n <notinfile> -a <areinfile> b")
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-b", "--bfile"):
            binputfilename = arg
        elif opt in ("-s", "--sfile"):
            sinputfilename = arg
        elif opt in ("-n", "--nfile"):
            outputfilename1 = arg
        elif opt in ("-a", "--afile"):
            outputfilename2 = arg
        elif len(sys.argv[1:]) > 4 or len(sys.argv[1:]) < 4:
            print(str(sys.argv[0]) + " -b <biggerfile> -s <smallerfile> -n <notinfile> -a <areinfile> c")
            sys.exit(2)
    #smallset = set(open(sinputfilename).read().split())
    #bigset = set(open(binputfilename).read().split()) 

    with open(sinputfilename, 'r') as smallsetsrc, open(binputfilename, 'r') as bigsetsrc, open(outputfilename1, 'w') as outfile1, open(outputfilename2, 'w') as outfile2:
        smallset = set(line.strip() for line in smallsetsrc)
        bigset = set(line.strip() for line in bigsetsrc)
        #find the elements in smallfile that arent in bigfile
        outset1 = smallset.difference(bigset)
        #find the elements in small file that ARE in bigfile
        outset2 = smallset.intersection(bigset)

        count = 0
        for msisdn in outset1:
            count += 1 
            #outfile1.write("%s, %s, %s, %s\n" % (str(count)+".", msisdn)) 
            print(str(count), msisdn) 
#        count = 0
#        for msisdn in outset2:
#            count += 1 
#            outfile2.write("%s, %s, %s, %s\n" % (str(count)+".", msisdn)) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main(sys.argv[1:])
    except IOError, e:
        print(str(sys.argv[0]) + " -b <biggerfile> -s <smallerfile> -n <notinfile> -a <areinfile> d")
        print("I/O error: {0}".format(str(e)))
        print(sys.exc_info())
```

Comment: Simple, files doesn't exists in path provided

Comment: Fortunately the files do exist, I created them myself.

Comment: The files may exist, but the variables that are supposed to contain their names aren't actually getting set. I'd start by leaving them uninitialized; when you try to use the variable that isn't set, you'll get a `NameError`.

Comment: Related, don't use `getopts` to parse your arguments. (It's intended primarily to ease porting code from other languages that are using the same library.) Use `argparse` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code using `argparse` instead of `getopts`, which should better ensure that the correct names are being specified. (Typically, I don't like required options; I would use positional arguments instead.)

Note that you don't need to open the files at same time; only open the one you need, and only for as long as you are using it.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse

def main():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument("-b", "--bfile", required=True)
    p.add_argument("-s", "--sfile", required=True)
    p.add_argument("-n", "--nfile", required=True)
    p.add_argument("-a", "--afile" required=True)
    args = p.parse_args()

    with open(args.sfile) as smallsetsrc:
        smallset = set(line.strip() for line in smallsetsrc)

    with open(args.bfile) as bigsetsrc:
        bigset = set(line.strip() for line in bigsetsrc)

    outset1 = smallset.difference(bigset)
    outset2 = smallset.intersection(bigset)

    with open(args.nfile, "w") as out:
        for count, msisdn in enumerate(outset1):
            print("%d. %s" % (count, msisdn), file=out) 

    with open(args.afile, "w") as out:
        for count, msisdn in enumerate(outset2):
            print("%d. %s" % (count, msisdn), file=out) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That was like, super fast. I barely got out of my seat before this arrived. Thanks!